# Change multiple items in a list at one time in Python

Tags: python, list

Can I change multiple items in a list at one time in Python?

Question1:
For example,my list is

```
lst=[0,0,0,0,0]
```

I want to the third and fifth item become 99.I know I can do it by

```
lst[2] = 99
lst[4] = 99
```

However, is there any easier way to do this?

Question2:in the situation,my target value is[99,98], my index is [2,4],so my result would be [0,0,99,0,98]. Is there any easy way to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could do like this,

```
>>> lst=[0,0,0,0,0]
>>> target = [99,98]
>>> pos = [2,4]
>>> for x,y in zip(pos,target):
        lst[x] = y


>>> lst
[0, 0, 99, 0, 98]
```

Comment: Thanks. What about if my target value is only one, do I have to generate a list like target_value = [99]*len(index). or there is an easy way to do this?

Comment: Yes, I think I'd do that. Just so that you're not duplicating the `for` loop in case you have conditions where you have multiple `target` values

Answer (score 5):

You can use [slice assignment](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-mutable) as long as the set of indices you're trying to assign to can be referenced by a slice (i.e. via start, stop, increment). For example:

```
lst=[0,0,0,0,0]
lst[2::2] = [99, 98]
print s
# [0, 0, 99, 0, 98]
```

Comment: Thanks. But I think I mean if there is no law in the index. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: For an arbitrary set of indices, you'll have to loop. See @Avinash Raj's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Using `numpy` also gives more control for such operations:

```
import numpy as np
lst = np.asarray([0,0,0,0,0])
lst[[2,4]]=[99, 100]

>>> lst
array([  0,   0,  99,   0, 100])
```

Answer (score 0):

For Question 1:

How about reducing it to one line?

You know you can do:

```py
lst[2] = 99
lst[4] = 99
```

You can also do:

```py
lst[2], lst[4] = 99, 99
```

Which will also result in:

```py
[0, 0, 99, 0, 99]
```