# How to set the same value in multiple index of array once python?

Tags: python, arrays

I have array like this:
a=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

i need to replace the value of the index 1 , 4 ,5 by the value 10 but without using for loop.

the result:
a=[1,10,3,4,10,10,7]

Comment: note homework,  in reality i have more than 1000index to be set with the same value. That is way i need solution

Comment: what is the criteria for using the index?

Comment: Maybe use a while loop then.

Comment: Why can't you use a for-loop then?

Comment: @ Pedro Maia , i don't want to use loop, because it take time

Comment: Michael Butscher, because i have a complexe algorithme and loop take time, may be there is solution with CUDA gpu

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change multiple items in a list at one time in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29425336/change-multiple-items-in-a-list-at-one-time-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you could utilize numpy for this:

```
import numpy as np
    
a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
    
indices = [1, 4, 5]
        
a.put(indices, 10)
```

result:

```
array([ 1, 10,  3,  4, 10, 10,  7])
```

Comment: Well, the beauty of using numpy is that you can use an index array as an..... index! Just do `a[indices] = 10`...

Answer (score 0):

Is this okay?

```
a[1] = a[4] = a[5] = 10
```

Comment: I have the index in array like this : index=[1,4,5],  this just example, in reality i have more 1000index to be set with the same value

Comment: Then there is no way without using a loop (as far as I know) @Asma01

Answer (score 0):

You can use numpy to do this.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
toChange = [1, 4, 5]
a[toChange] = 10 # changes all indices in toChange into 10
```

You may even pass a list to change each selected index into a different value using:

```
a[toChange] = [0, 1, 10]
```